# Date ranges filter filters same day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb-query

I'm setting up a rather simple date range filter for a datatable in AngularJS:

```
  if (vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date) { //data extracted from "From" input
    query.criteria.timestamp.$gte = vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date.toISOString();
  } else {
    vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date = query.criteria.timestamp.$gte = vm.minDate;
  }

  if (vm.datePopup.dateTo.date) { //data extracted from "To" input
    query.criteria.timestamp.$lte = vm.datePopup.dateTo.date.toISOString();
  }else {
    vm.datePopup.dateTo.date = query.criteria.timestamp.$lte = new Date();
  }
```

An example of date format would be `"2017-12-01T09:14:03.539Z"`.

Problem is, **I'm not getting data if same day is set in both inputs**, but I do if I set previous/next days. I suspect there is something to do with the format, but I cannot figure out how I can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and using a full qualified time for each day:

```
if (vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date) { //data extracted from "From" input
    query.criteria.timestamp.$gte = moment(vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date).startOf('day').toDate();
} else {
    vm.datePopup.dateFrom.date = query.criteria.timestamp.$gte = moment(vm.minDate).startOf('day').toDate();
}

if (vm.datePopup.dateTo.date) { //data extracted from "To" input
    query.criteria.timestamp.$lte = moment(vm.datePopup.dateTo.date).endOf('day').toDate();
} else {
    vm.datePopup.dateTo.date = query.criteria.timestamp.$lte = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
}
```